# Do systemd-fsck or fsck generate a status report?

Tags: systemd, fsck

How does one determine whether fsck operations were performed at bootup. I understand the default fsck config and behaviour, but is there a report or status that shows whether any fsck issues were found or repair operations were performed?

My system console does show a "clean" message but dmesg does not:

```
...
[  OK  ] Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
         Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[  OK  ] Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
         Starting Copy rules generated while the root was ro...
[  OK  ] Started Copy rules generated while the root was ro.
[    6.346472] systemd-fsck[171]: ROOTFS-A: clean, 26178/78240 files, 107613/312576 blocks
...
```

Perhaps there a standard API to query fsck operations and status, rather than looking at log files?

Comment: Hi!  I love this question. It seems the answer depends a bit e.g. on what initramfs generator you use (on whether the initramfs uses systemd or not).  Since you have given a specific example in your question, could you please specify exactly what OS and version it comes from.  Preferably also the version number of your systemd package.  And, while I am asking, are you using a specific initramfs generator, or just using the default initramfs that your distribution installed?

Comment: watch out, the log of fsck might not show up in journalctl under some circumstances. [In Ubuntu 16.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1619753) the log of the root partition fsck is in the initrd log in `/run/initramfs/fsck.log`.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for the `systemd` journal. `man journalctl` can be your entry point. To review the logs for `systemd-fsck` you can look at:

```
journalctl -u systemd-fsck*
```

As you'll see in `man journalctl`, there are are also machine-friendly output options like JSON. That's as close as you are going to come to an API to query fsck status, besides the other systemd tool for querying service status:

```
systemctl status systemd-fsck*
```

As you'll see in `man systemctl`, it also offers machine-friendly output formats as well.

I'm aware of no way to query `fsck` status without `systemd`.

Comment: I did try journalctl but realized that it was deconfigured NOT to log from syslog. However, syslog does show the console "clean" message.

Comment: Regarding systemctl, it only shows the the status of the systemd-fsck service, and its exit code.

Comment: Github for systemd-fsck also indicates that all fsck "progress" goes to /dev/console, with several unique exits codes.

Comment: The solution looks like a combination of journal and syslog scrubbing operations. No standard API for status :(

Comment: @awoz - `fsck` at boot time is run from `initramfs` so there's no filesystem to write to, though some distros work around that and save the output to `/run/initramfs/*` or `/var/log/fsck/*`

Comment: @don_crissti a lot of distros work around it by saving the output in a ring buffer in `/run/systemd/journal` (and hoping they have enough space to keep all the output), which is then saved to the persistent journal if/when it becomes available.  :-P.  At least if they use `dracut` initramfs.

Comment: @don_crissti I suspect that the *root* filesystem `fsck` is done in the initramfs (and maybe `/usr` as well), but the rest of the `fsck` will be done on the main system, so you might have to look in two different places :-(.

Comment: @awoz this command works for me on Fedora, and github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v240/units/… doesn't override `StandardOutput=`, so it should just write to the journal.  One possibility is you traced log_setup_service() and guessed wrong about where the logs go.  But, I do not know why you are seeing this output on the console on your current system.

Comment: btw, its embedded jessie, early systemd-215, with disk image (no initrd).
-thx

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm **don_crissti** response above.

For my Beaglebone running Debian 8.3 (Jessie), the result is in **/run/initramfs/fsck.log**

I have **fsck.mode=force** and **fsck.repair=yes**  set in **/boot/uEnv.txt** for Kernel command line options

```
root@beaglebone:~# more /run/initramfs/fsck.log
Log of fsck -C -f -y -V -t ext4 /dev/mmcblk0p1
Thu Jun 28 13:52:24 2018
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/mmcblk0p1] 
fsck.ext4 -f -y -C0 /dev/mmcblk0p1
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
BOOT: 38273/240000 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 284298/958208 blocks

root@beaglebone:~# cat /etc/dogtag
BeagleBoard.org Debian Image 2016-02-15

root@beaglebone:~# more /etc/debian_version
8.3

root@beaglebone:~# uname -a
Linux beaglebone 4.1.17-ti-rt-r48 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Fri Feb 12 23:46:00 UTC 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```