# How to show journal messages from all `fsck` units

Tags: systemd, fsck, journalctl

Is there a reasonable procedure for a system administrator to view all the `fsck` messages?

---

On my current Fedora 29 system, I can view all the `fsck` messages from my current boot like this:

```
sudo journalctl -b /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-fsck
```

However, it is a hack that assumes `fsck` writes messages to `stdout` / `stderr`.  It does not allow for a hypothetical `fsck` which detects that it is run from systemd, and sends log messages through the syslog or journald socket e.g. in order to set appropriate "priority" for each message.

Is there a cleaner method, that works even if some `fsck` sends its log messages directly to journald?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo journalctl -b -u 'systemd-fsck*'
```

---

The credit for this answer belongs here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436033/29483

A second answer on the linked question notes that this method will not work on all systems, even if the system uses `systemd`.  One reason is if the `initramfs`, which runs `fsck` on the root filesystem (and `/usr`), does not use `systemd`.  In this case the initramfs might arrange to save its `fsck` logs somewhere else, not in the journal.

You can also use `sudo systemctl status 'systemd-fsck*'`, and it will work perfectly well according to my analysis.  Although I cannot think of a reason why you would prefer this.  `systemctl status` only shows the last ten messages for each unit by default.